# Error when using font awesome in Angular 17 library

Tags: angularjs, font-awesome

I am build components in a library using bootstrap and font awesome icons. The library has been built with no error. However when I use the library in an angular project, I got this error:

NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203

Any advice on how to use font awesome icon in an angular library?

I have tested it with the latest version of angular and font awesome.

Comment: Note that starting from angular 17.2 you can typescript import svgs: [more info](https://medium.com/netanelbasal/simplifying-file-imports-in-angular-with-new-loader-options-4e94a0eb18af)